# xampp symfony5 doctrine query encoding

Tags: symfony, xampp, doctrine

I have problem with encoding polish characters in doctrine query. I've tried sqlite and mysql with the same problem.
I send query string and in controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/find/{query}", name="find_query")
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
 * 
 * @param LocationRepository $locationRepository
 * @param string             $query
 * @param Request            $request
 * 
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function locationSearchApi(LocationRepository $locationRepository, string $query, Request $request)
{
    dump($query);
    $locations = $locationRepository->search($query);

    $data = [
        'data'  => $locations,
        'count' => \is_array($locations) ? \count($locations) : 0,
    ];

    return $this->json($data);
}
```

Now when I'm sendig GET query `/find/okr%C4%99%C5%BCna` (okrężna) then in debuger I have correct string `$query = "okrężna"` but doctrine resolves this as binary

```
Parameters:
[▼
  b"okrä™å¾na"
  b"okrä™å¾na"
]
```

and returns nothing. In database is UTF-8 encoding and I see proper characters.

When I use string without any polish character doctrine sends correct query

```
Parameters:
[▼
  "hubala"
  "hubala"
]
```

On Linux machine everything works fine. Problem is when I've moved this to Win10.

I chaged character encoding to utf8 in php.ini, phpinfo() also shows utf8 but doctrine encodes string to binary.

in **doctrine.yaml** I changed to utf8 also

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        charset: UTF8
    #    charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_polish_ci
```

I've tried utf8mb4, utf8 but without results

How to fix it?

Comment: Why not use slugs instead the original language?

Comment: Because this is locations database provided from outside